# Add Telerik Grid Control in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, telerik, telerik-grid

I am developing a Web Application purely based on HTML as well as Javascript. 
In that application i want to use Telerik RadGrid Control. As we all know that HTML is client Side based and Telerik Controls are Server side based. So my question is can we use telerik Rad Controls in our HTML Page? IF YES could you please share your experience with me.
Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not used "telerik Rad Controls" in your html page. For html page you have to use [Kendo-UI](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html) control.